# Nodejs/Express - Why is there a need for app inside of http.createServer(app)?

Tags: node.js, express

```
// get dependencies
const express = require("express");
const http = require('http');
const app = express();

const server = http.createServer(app);
```

Why is there a need for app inside of http.createServer(app)? What is the difference between that and http.createServer()?

I've read the documentation but I still don't understand. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `app` is passed to `http.createServer` is related to [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), a pattern for defining external dependencies.

`http.createServer` accepts external Classes that will be used internally to handle incoming messages and outgoing responses.

This allows you to write your own Classes to handle incoming/outgoing messages, without modifying `http`'s internals yourself. In your case you are using Express's classes.

Answer (score 1):

The method createServer expects an object that will define how the requests to the server will be handled. Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_http_createserver.asp). The app that you pass is in fact how you want each request handled. If you did not pass anything to it, it would just start a server and nothing would happen on each request received.

Comment: The actual reason is related to [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). `http.createServer` accepts Classes that can be used to handle incoming/outgoing request/responses. What you're saying might be the effect but it's not the reason why `app` is passed to `http.createServer`.

Comment: You are correct about Dependency Injection. My answer was more to the "What is the difference between that and http.createServer()?" and to that he does not understand why he has to pass the app to the function in a logical level.